# How to filter CGPoints in an NSArray by CGRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` with `CGPoints`. I'd like to filter this array by only including points within a rect.

How can I formulate an `NSPredicate` such that each point satisfies this predicate:

> CGRectContainsPoint(windowRect, point);

Here's the code so far:

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pointAtYZero] ,
                                             [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pointAtYHeight],
                                             [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pointAtXZero],
                                             [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pointAtXWidth],
                                             nil];


NSPredicate *inWindowPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CGRectContainsPoint(windowRect, [point CGPointValue])"];
NSArray *filteredPoints = [points filteredArrayUsingPredicate:inWindowPredicate];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do this with the predicate format syntax, but you can use a block:

```
NSArray *points = ...;
CGRect windowRect = ...;    
NSPredicate *inWindowPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    CGPoint point = [evaluatedObject CGPointValue];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(windowRect, point);
}];
NSArray *filteredPoints = [points filteredArrayUsingPredicate:inWindowPredicate];
```

Note that it's not possible to use block-based predicates for Core Data fetch requests.

Comment: You can also skip the predicate and just obtain the elements passing a test specified by a block: `NSArray* filteredPoints = [points objectsAtIndexes:[points indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){ return CGRectContainsPoint(windowRect, [obj CGPointValue]); }]];`

Comment: @KenThomases, why dont you post it as an answer?

Comment: Because omz's answer is basically correct and my suggestion is just a refinement. The OP *did* ask "How can I formulate an `NSPredicate` …". :)

Comment: the title is "How to filter CGPoints in an NSArray by CGRect", so your answer is valid

Comment: @omz, I did exactly that, but my program was crashing. I naturally assumed that the predicate was the culprit. I guess the bug is some place else.